# MongoDb to spingboot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

```
aggregate(\[{"$match" : {"date": { "$l t": new Date(), "$g t e": new Date(new Date().set 
Date(new Date().get Date()-7))}}}, 
{your text"$group": {"\_id" : "$date","quantity" : { $sum : "$quantity"}}}\])
```

This is my mongo aggregate query and want to use in spring boot. please share your solution
`your text`
This is my mongo aggregate query and want to use in spring boot. please share your solution

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to define the below method in the DAO interface:

```
public interface ISampleDAO extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
  
@Aggregation(pipeline ={"{'$match':{'date':{$lt:'?0',$gte:'?1'}}}","{'$group':{'_id':'$date','quantity':{'$sum':'$quantity'}}}"})
       List<T> getResult(Date ltDate,Date gteDate);
}
```